# About PHP Magic Methods __get and __set on inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, magic-methods

**OBS:** I coded directly here, beacause my code is much more complex.

If I code:

```
class SuperFoo {
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }
    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

class Foo extends SuperFoo {
    private $bar = '';
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar = "Why it doesn't work?";
var_dump($foo);
```

Results in:

```
object(Foo) {
    ["bar":"Foo":private]=> 
        string(0) ''
}
```

And not in:

```
object(Foo) {
    ["bar":"Foo":private]=> 
        string(20) 'Why it doesn't work?'
}
```

Why this happen? I don't want to use an array to hold the attributes, because I need them declared as individual private members.

Comment: On the code sample you provided class Foo doesn't even extend SuperFoo, so this is supposed to happen. Check the code you provided, please.

Comment: you missed the `public function` in front of `__get` and `__set`.

Comment: I got: `Fatal error: Cannot access private property Foo::$bar `

Comment: [That doesn't even compile](http://ideone.com/ZcebjQ)

Comment: Sorry, I coded directly because my code is much more complex. But the problem is there. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Your code should be resulting in a fatal error because you're trying to access a private property. Even before that, you should receive a syntax error because you haven't properly declared your functions. Hence, you're "resulting" var dump can never occur.</strike>

### Edit:

You've edited your question. **The reason it doesn't work is because `bar` is private to `Foo`** (`SuperFoo` cannot access it). Make it `protected` instead.

Comment: I updated the question. Please, read the update, maybe you can help me.

Comment: And we get no *Cannot access private property* because `SuperFoo` is creating its own `$bar` attribute?

Comment: I don't believe so, Álvaro. PHP will not create a property with more visibility than is in its subclass (dynamically created properties would be public but it's already private in `Foo`). It appears to just silently fail.

Answer (score 3):

[`__get($name)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) **isn't** called if object has attribute called `$name`, but it tries to use the attribute directly. And your attribute is private, thus error.

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.
>
> __get() is utilized for reading data from inaccessible properties.

Comment: Thank you for understanding the problem.

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question. There's no error triggered in the original code—instead, the attribute modification is apparently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If **Foo::bar** is **private**, **Foo** needs to override **__get** and **__set**. This is because **SuperFoo** can't access private members of **Foo**.  The following code works but it's ugly:

```
class SuperFoo {
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

class Foo extends SuperFoo {
    private $bar = '';

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

The proper solution is to modify **Foo::bar** visibility to **protected**.  Now **SuperFoo** has access to **Foo::bar** so there's no need to override **__get** and **__set** in **Foo**.

```
class SuperFoo {
    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

class Foo extends SuperFoo {
    protected $bar = '';
}
```

**[Check out the PHP Documentation on visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)**